# fgets(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am testing with PayPals example IPN code which should return `valid`, or `invalid` for a transaction. I am testing with PayPals IPN simulator which should send some dummy data, and then validate it (returning "Valid").

I am testing with two separate web servers, both have OpenSSL installed and enabled.

On our local web server, we get this error message.

`fgets(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

On our clients web server, with the same code, we get this:

`fgets() [<a href='function.fgets'>function.fgets</a>]: SSL: Connection reset by peer in ...../paypal_ipn.php on line 43`

PayPal doesn't seem to have a non-SSL version of this anymore.

**paypal_ipn.php**:

```
    <?php

    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "error.log");

       // Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification 
       header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 

       // Assign payment notification values to local variables
       //$item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
       //$item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
       $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
       $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
       $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
       $txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'];
       $receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
       $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];

         // Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
      $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // Add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of the acknowledgement

    $req .= '&'.http_build_query($_POST);


      // Set up the acknowledgement request headers
      $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                    // HTTP POST request
      $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

      // Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
  //$fp = fsockopen('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  //$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);   
    if ($fp === FALSE) {
        error_log("Could not open socket");
        exit("Could not open socket");
    }

      // Send the HTTP POST request back to PayPal for validation
      fputs($fp, $header . $req);

      while (!feof($fp)) {                     // While not EOF
        $res = fgets($fp, 1024);               // Get the acknowledgement response
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response contains VERIFIED - process notification

          // Send an email announcing the IPN message is VERIFIED
          $mail_From    = "IPN@example.com";
          $mail_To      = "Your-eMail-Address";
          $mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
          $mail_Body    = $req;
          file_put_contents("log.txt", "valid: " . $req, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);


          // Authentication protocol is complete - OK to process notification contents

          // Possible processing steps for a payment include the following:

          // Check that the payment_status is Completed
          // Check that txn_id has not been previously processed
          // Check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
          // Check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
          // Process payment

        } 
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { //Response contains INVALID - reject notification

          // Authentication protocol is complete - begin error handling

          // Send an email announcing the IPN message is INVALID
          $mail_From    = "IPN@example.com";
          $mail_To      = "Your-eMail-Address";
          $mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
          $mail_Body    = $req;
            file_put_contents("log.txt", "invalid: " . $req, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

        }
      }

      fclose($fp);  // Close the file
    ?>
```

I am not going to be using CURL, as that is whole other lot of problems! Can anyone see what could be causing these two (separate) errors?

EDIT:

I've just tested on another server running XAMPP (nearly everything enabled), and I now get this 'error':

`PHP Warning:  fgets(): SSL: The operation completed successfully.`

Yet, the transaction doesn't get validated at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right well after a day of struggling with this, I went home, and decided to tackle it this morning.

It looked like there was an issue with using fget / fputs. I could browse to the verification URL using the post data in my browser and could see that the URL I was using was working fine.

I couldn't use CURL due to some other issues and not enough time to solve them.

***Solution***:

Use `file_get_contents()` instead. This made things easier, and no need to send headers or anything else. This works flawlessly!

```
  $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $req;

  $res = file_get_contents($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact problem today but after a couple hours I finally located the root cause. It's perfectly fine to use [Paypal's original PHP code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) but unfortunately it's fairly outdated ever since they switched over to HTTPS. In order to use fgets, you'll need to include the HOST in the header. For a quick fix, here is the code sample I used:

```
    $parsed_url = parse_url('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // Development (sandbox) or production URL
    $header  = "POST $parsed_url[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: $parsed_url[host]\r\n";
```

Hope it works for you.