# laravel schedule jobs not executed

Tags: laravel, scheduler, jobs

I have several jobs in my scheduler:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new PingDatabase())->everyFiveMinutes();
    $schedule->job(new ImportInstagram())->hourly();
    $schedule->job(new ImportBlog())->hourly();
    $schedule->job(new SendEmails())->dailyAt('11:00');
}
```

I just realized that the SendEmails job did not get triggered today.
Could this be because I use the sync queue driver and the jobs take too long?

Comment: are you running the corn job ?

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara yes. Cronjob is setup

Comment: do u have any logs on your laravel.logs? may be you can trace there. may be it execute but it catches error inside

Comment: @TonzFale There was indeed an error in the logs:
 file_get_contents(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

However. I am not sure about the cause

Comment: @TonzFale Ok I found the problem. I was loading an external page, which failed. Thank you

Comment: you have same problem with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837345/fgets-ssl-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host

but did you use MAIL helper for email when sending in laravel? file_get_contents() is like an error from curl or guzzle.

can you share your SendEmails code?

Comment: oh great.  that was good